# Fairest way to choose gifts

Tags: game-theory, oc.optimization-and-control, recreational-mathematics, fair-division, economics

Suppose that a parent brings home from a trip $2n$ gifts of roughly  equal value for his/her two children. The children get to choose one  at a time which gifts they want. What is the fairest way to do this?

For instance, if $n=1$ then clearly one child chooses first (determined by a coin flip) and the other child chooses second. If we denote the children by 0 and 1, then this method is described by the  choice sequence 01 (assuming, as I do from now on, that 0 chooses  first). Now suppose $n=2$. The choice sequence 0101 is clearly biased  toward 0, since 0 has the first choice at the beginning and after both have chosen one gift. The fairest sequence by any reasonable criterion is 0110.

What about general $n$?  If $n=2^k$, an argument can be made that the fairest sequence is the first $n$ terms of the Thue-Morse sequence (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseSequence.html).

Another argument can be made that the fairest sequence $a_1,\dots, a_n$ is one  that maximizes the value of $k$ for which the polynomial $(1-2a_1)x^{n-1} + (1-2a_2)x^{n-2}+\cdots+(1-2a_n)$ and its first $k$  derivatives vanish at $x=1$. (The Thue-Morse sequence does not have  this property, though I cannot recall where I once saw this.)

Has this problem received any attention? What is a reference for the problem of maximizing $k$?

Comment: For dividing an estate with large items, a house, cars, each heir makes a secret bid or monetary "value" estimate on each indivisible item. Then there is a spreadsheet technique for assigning items, which along with some actual money changing hands has every heir doing at least as well as the others, insofar as their personal estimates of value. No real reference, I taught this in a course for nonmajors with a book by the COMAP project called "For All Practical Purposes." Your problem seems harder, can't expect children to submit written estimates, sequential may be only possible.  

Comment: You need more assumptions, if you want to prove that something i fair. E.g. you might assume that the value of a gift is uniformly distributed in some interval $[1,1+\epsilon]$ with $\epsilon<1/n$. Another question is, if the two children agree on the value of a gift. If they do, then I think the cake dividing algorithm (for two persons) would be optimal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_division 

Comment: What I meant was the divide and choose protocol: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_choose 

Comment: I can't believe MO does not have any "fair division" or "social choice" tags...

Comment: Thierry, see my post at the very end (third page) of this Meat thread:
$$ $$
http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/34/3/tag-mergerename-requests/#Comment_8740   
$$ $$
There is always a chance the link will take you directly to my post, it has a number at the end.
$$ $$
Meanwhile, you have enough points to create new tags, but there appear to be several posiibilities here.




Comment: I intended to type Meta, I really did, one of those Freudian things.

Comment: @Will: thanks! When I posted my first comment, I automatically assumed that I didn't have enough rep to create tags myself. Still, I've been on MO for less than a month, so the wisest course seems to be to use discretion in my newly found powers. :-)

Comment: I also started a separate thread where this is the initial post.  
$$  $$
I am glad that you have chosen to use your powers for good.
$$ $$


Comment: since coins are allowed couldn't we just pick a number uniformly at random from $0...2^{2n} - 1$ and then use it's binary representation as the sequence of choices with 0 = Alice and 1 = Bobby? or are we restricted in the number of coin flips we are allowed to make?

Comment: @Artem, if you happen to pick 0 you will have a riot on your hands. 

Comment: I made a fair-division tag, as this particular problem fits that better than voting theory. The meta thread is still there, in case something else is preferred. However, most discussion is on similar tags that should be merged, rather than completely new tags. 

Comment: The ordering for fair division becomes even more interesting if you allow for unequal values of the gifts; however, that also adds the extra factors of disparate valuation of the gifts by different children, becoming more like an economist's or sociologist's experiment on optimal strategies.

Answer (score 12):

Hello,

I've been lurking on mathoverflow for a while.  I am not a research mathematician, just a rank amateur.

Forgive me if I'm missing any etiquette.

Steven J. Brams and Alan D. Taylor discussed the Morse-Thue solution in their book ''The Win-Win Solution,'' ISBN-10: 0393320812, although it's a popular-math book and I'm not sure if they name it.  I think they call it "picking sides picking sides."

Brian Hayes blogged of this problem on his bit-player:

http://bit-player.org/2007/choosing-up-sides-again

Best,
Mark

Answer (score 11):

Here's an idea.  For any partition $(A,B)$ of $[2n]$, where $|A|=|B|=n$, we can ask each child if they prefer $A$ or $B$.  If one prefers $A$ and the other prefers $B$, then we are done.  Otherwise, they have the same preference function over all such partitions.

**Lemma.** There exists partitions $(A,B)$ and $(A',B')$ such that

1. both children prefer $A$ over $B$,
2. both children prefer $B'$ over $A'$, and
3. $(A',B')$ is obtained from $(A,B)$ by performing a single swap.

**Proof.** Perform swaps until $(A,B)$ becomes $(B,A)$.  At some point, each child must switch preferences.

Given the assumption that the gifts are all roughly the same value, it seems fair to offer such an $(A,B)$ as a choice and to flip a coin to decide who gets $A$.

Comment: @Tony,

While mathematically, your reasoning is sound, I must state that children (and adults dealing with money) do not behave rationally and do not behave consistently.  Their **valuation function** is not just a function of the parameters of the question at hand, but often also a function of fime and a function of what your *opponent* wants in these economic games.  Younger siblings also tend to want what the older sibling wants, or *vice versa*, in order to confound their rivals intention.  Thus "each child **must** switch preferences" is not going to work in real life.

Comment: I certainly agree that there is a lot of idealization going on. This reminds me of a similar problem I heard back in the day. Namely, suppose 3 friends have just moved into a 3 bedroom house. They are trying to decide who gets which room, and how much rent each should pay. The rooms can be highly heterogeneous, and each person can have different preferences. It turns out that using Sperner's Lemma, one can prove that there exists a partition $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ of the rent such that for each $i \in [3]$, person $i$ chooses room $i$ (with rent $p_i$) over the other two rooms.

Comment: Does your lemma apply only to the case where the two children have the same preference function?

Comment: Yes, but this is the hard case.  As I mention if they have different preference functions then we can offer them a choice where they are both 'happy' (or at least not jealous of the other).  The lemma is false in general if they have different preference functions. For example it is possible that for all partitions $(A,B)$ one child prefers $A$ and the other prefers $B$.  

Comment: When you (Tony) explain it, it sounds so simple. :)  This seems to be a very interesting problem, especially if the gifts have different values, then you would have to consider having different sizes for the two partitions.  Does anyone know if this general case has been studied before?

Answer (score 7):

Concerning the question of a reference for maximizing $k$:

A polynomial with all coefficients $\pm1$ is called a Littlewood polynomial, see, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_polynomial. The question of Littlewood polynomials vanishing to high order at $x=1$ is in the literature. See, e.g., Daniel Berend and Shahar Golan, Littlewood polynomials with high order zeros, Math Comp 75 (2006) 1541-1552, freely available at https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2006-75-255/S0025-5718-06-01848-5/S0025-5718-06-01848-5.pdf Executive summary; some numbers are known, some bounds are known, much remains to be done.

Answer (score 5):

The following paper apparently addresses exactly the question that you are interested in:

[A General Elicitation-free Protocol for Allocating Indivisible Goods,  by: Sylvain Bouveret and Jérôme Lang, International Joint Conference on Artificial Intelligence (2011)](https://doi.org/10.5591/978-1-57735-516-8/ijcai11-024).